# Facebook Javascript API - Having trouble 'connecting'

Tags: javascript, api, facebook

Here's the code I've been testing with:

```
<?php
$accessToken = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials');
$accessToken = explode('=', $accessToken);
$accessToken = $accessToken[1];
?>
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function()
{
    FB.init({
        appId:  'APP_ID',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml:  true
    });

    FB.api('/me?access_token=<?php echo $accessToken; ?>', function(user)
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
            console.log(user);
        }
    });
};

(function()
{
    var e   = document.createElement('script');
    e.type  = 'text/javascript';
    e.src   = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js';
    e.async = true;

    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>
```

I'm getting the following error returned:

```
An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

I registered my site URL with Facebook to get my ID/Secret and am running the above script within the directory I specified when registering.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing things up here, trying to access user information with an `App access_token`!

Have a read of the [Authentication document](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), the `User login` section. Also I would ***strongly*** recommend the use the [Facebook PHP-SDK](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk), where the library will take care of all the authentication and authorization exchange process.

Comment: i second that, Facebook PHP is way better !

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using old rest api to get access token why you dont use graph api to get access token?

```
define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID', 'Your API ID');
define('FACEBOOK_SECRET', 'YOUR SECRET');
function get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $application_secret)
{
    $args = array();
    parse_str(trim($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id], '\\"'), $args);
    ksort($args);
    $payload = '';
    foreach ($args as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($key != 'sig')
        {
            $payload .= $key . '=' . $value;
        }
    }
    if (md5($payload . $application_secret) != $args['sig'])
    {
        return null;
    }
    return $args;
}
$cookie = get_facebook_cookie(FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_SECRET);
$name=json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.$cookie['access_token']));
```

I think its prettey simple